# kendo dialog pop up opened multi time with multi click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my grid.js

```
template: "<div>#if(data.c> 0){#<a class='undo' onClick='showDiv(#:id#)'>#:c# test</a>#} else{#N/A#}#</div>",
```

first I have bind data like above.

in my showDiv function

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dialog = $('#dialog'),
                undo = $('.undo');

            console.log("first");

            undo.click(function () {

                console.log("second");

                dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
                undo.fadeOut();
            });
            function onClose() {                  
                undo.fadeIn();
            }

            dialog.kendoDialog({
                width: "450px",
                title: "Site Name",
                closable: false,
                modal: false,
                content: data,
                actions: [                     
                    { text: 'close'}
                ],
                close: onClose
            });
        });

    }
});
```

as I  log first and second , for each click first console log one time but second  each click increasing.
let say I clicked 2 time then   console log for second   is two time .

because of this I need to close 2 time .

seen 2:- if I click line 2 ,one time and line 3 one time , then third try with line 2 click , need to close 2 time and data populated from line 2 for first close and line 3 for second close .

what is the issue here . any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding new handler to `.undo` click event each time showDiv function is executed. The easiest way to fix this is to change

```
undo.click(function () {
```

to [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
undo.one('click', function () {
```

added handler will be executed only once after binding.